# TypeError: Cannot read property 'defaultMeta' of undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, undefined

So I'm coding a search engine in TypeScript. I have this error, where like it tells me that `index.domains[host]` is undefined. But when I debug in vscode, it says everything is working fine and that `defaultMeta` **does** exist on every domain in the list. The error occurs in search.ts, line 27.

I am pretty new to TS, started in feburary this year.

Error that im getting:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'defaultMeta' of undefined
    at C:\none of ur business\search-engine\search\src\apis\search.js:21:49
    at Array.map (<anonymous>)
    at default_1 (C:\none of ur business\search-engine\search\src\apis\search.js:18:27)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\none of ur business\search-engine\search\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
    at next (C:\none of ur business\search-engine\search\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:137:13)
    at Route.dispatch (C:\none of ur business\search-engine\search\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:112:3)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\none of ur business\search-engine\search\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
    at C:\none of ur business\search-engine\search\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:281:22
    at Function.process_params (C:\none of ur business\search-engine\search\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:335:12)
    at next (C:\none of ur business\search-engine\search\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:275:10)
```

search.ts:

```
import { readFileSync } from "fs";
import { filePaths } from "../../../config.json";

export default function(req, res) {
    res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");

    if (req.query.q) {

        const timeStart = process.hrtime();

        const index = JSON.parse(readFileSync(filePaths.indexDb, "utf-8"));

        const query = req.query.q.toLowerCase()
        .replace(/[^\w\d ]/g, "");

        var results = index.crawled.filter(page => {
            return page.url.toLowerCase().includes(query) || page.meta.title?.toLowerCase()?.includes(query);
        });

        const resultsAmount = results.length;
        results = results.slice((req.query.pg || 0) * 20, (req.query.pg || 0) * 20 + 20);

        results = results.map(page => {
            const url = new URL(page.url);
            const host = /^(www\.)/.test(url.host) ? url.host.substr(4) : url.host;
            const defMeta = index.domains[host].defaultMeta; // here is the error

            return {
                url: page.url,
                title: page.meta.title === undefined ? defMeta.title : page.meta.title,
                desc: page.meta.desc === undefined ? defMeta.desc : page.meta.desc
            }
        });

        const timeEnd = process.hrtime(timeStart);
        const timeSecs = Math.round((timeEnd[0] * 1e9 + timeEnd[1]) / 1e9 * 100) / 100;

        return res.json({
            success: true,
            resultsAmount,
            timeTaken: timeSecs,
            results
        });
    } else {
        return res.status(400)
        .json({
            success: false,
            msg: "Invalid query"
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: FYI: You're not using any TypeScript in your code. It's a JavaScript issue.

Answer (score 0):

Your errors points out that the field where `defaultMeta` should be called on does not exist. That is, `domains[host]` does not exist in line

```
const defMeta = index.domains[host].defaultMeta; // here is the error
```

This means that if `domains[host]` does not exist, you cannot continue to require field `defaultMeta` from it.

You can do this by surrounding your problematic line with an if condition which checks whether it's defined:

```js
if (index.domains[host] !== undefined) {
  const defMeta = index.domains[host].defaultMeta; // here is the error

  return {
      url: page.url,
      title: page.meta.title === undefined ? defMeta.title : page.meta.title,
      desc: page.meta.desc === undefined ? defMeta.desc : page.meta.desc
  }
}
```

You see how I also included the following lines into the `if` statement. That's because you're using `defMeta` there which would not be defined if `index.domains[host]` is not defined.

Alternatively you could also use the [optional chaining operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining) `?.` to only access values in case they are defined. But here you would also have to then make sure future uses are checked (see all the places where I used `?.`:

```js
if (index.domains[host] !== undefined) {
  const defMeta = index.domains?.[host]?.defaultMeta; // here is the error

  return {
      url: page.url,
      title: page.meta.title === undefined ? defMeta?.title : page.meta.title,
      desc: page.meta.desc === undefined ? defMeta?.desc : page.meta.desc
  }
}
```

---

So perhaps you have to analyze why `index.domains[host]` is undefined in the first place. This could be because your `const host = /^(www\.)/.test(url.host) ? url.host.substr(4) : url.host;` line might have an error?!